# drillthrough on text (not cell)

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Just want to know if this is even possible, before I drive myself insane in google-searches.

I know how to drillthrough to another rapport when the user clicks on a cell. But what if the cell has multiple values, e.g. Server-names (comma-seperated), and I only want to pass the servername that the user clicked?

As I see you can only pass the values of the whole cell or what?

Using reporting services 2012 R2 with report builder 3.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that directly but...

You could create a subreport that accepts the comma separated list of servers as it's parameter. 
The subreport would then split these into separate cells and have an action on the cell that then take you to the drill through report. I done something similar in the past and it's work quite nicely. You just need to make the subreport nice and small so it'll fit in you existing cell.

It you wanted to keep them on a single line then subreport would have to be a matrix with a column group grouped by servername. It won't be as compact as a comma separated list as the columns will all have to be wide enough to fit the longest name but it works.

If you need any more help I'll provide more more detailed solution but this hopefully will get you going.